# How can i copy the object position to the edit position to meet the rest position?

Tags: modeling

When i switch from object to edit mode, the model changes the position. What i found out so far is that this is related to the "rest position". http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/Advanced_Tutorials/Advanced_Animation/Guided_tour/Armature/object

But how can i change the rest position to look the same as the object position? Because if i change the rest position the object position changes too, thus always a margin of differences... can i just copy past the object position into the edit position/rest position?

Answer (score 1):

Any movement done in pose mode will also be shown in object mode, any keyframed movement will change this position as you change the current frame.

One option you have is to clear any pose mode changes made. While in pose mode press <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> and <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> to clear the location, rotation and scale of the selected bones, putting the armature back into the rest position.

Another option is to set the current position as the rest position by pressing <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and choosing "Apply pose as Rest Pose"